# Catch enter press in flash block on webpage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have a webpage with a flash header. In the flash header (block), different dropdownmenus are present together with a 'submit' button.

When the user presses 'enter', i want to submit the form.
However, I can't seem to be able to catch any key :

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownFunc); 
root.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownFunc); 
optiesPanelNew.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownFunc); 
optiesPanelNew.ddOptiesMerk.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownFunc); 

function onKeyDownFunc(evt)
{
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        submitForm();
    }
}
```

This javascript works if the html part of the page (non flash) has focus :

```
document.body.onkeydown = function theFunction()
{
    alert("keydown");
}
```

**Edit:** Oh no, the flash file was written in AS2 ... sorry :-/
FYI : the code I ended up using was :  (AS2) :

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function():Void
{
    if(Key.getCode()==13)
        submitForm();

}

Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the event's type in the handler (i.e. `KeyboardEvent`) because this way the dispatched object will be cast to a `Event` object when its instance is passed to the handler. The `Event` class doesn't have the **keyCode** property, and subsequently the condition to submit the form is not met. That's why the form doesn't get submitted.

So, try replacing the

```
function onKeyDownFunc(evt)
```

line, with

```
function onKeyDownFunc(evt:KeyboardEvent)
```

and it should do the trick.

Have a great day.